# HTML URL extraction with regex in Python - Start (https) and ending (jpg)

Tags: python, html, regex

I'm trying to extract the links that appear in the URL but the regex brings me much more information. I'm trying to generate a list of the URLs.
What is missing from the regex to find them?

```
import urllib.request
import numpy as np
import codecs
import unicodedata
from itertools import chain

import os 
import re

url = "https://www.shutterstock.com/es/g/monkographic?searchterm=cabro"
request = urllib.request.Request(url)
response = urllib.request.urlopen(request)
data_content = response.read()
html = data_content.decode('ISO-8859-1')

imgUrls = re.findall(r'https:(.+?)jpg', html)
imgUrls


 Expected result 

"https:\\u002F\\u002Fimage.shutterstock.com\\u002Fimage-vector\\u002Fman-standing-looks-lcd-monitor-260nw-1033361050.jpg
"https:\\u002F\\u002Fimage.shutterstock.com\\u002Fimage-vector\\u002Fman-standing-looks-lcd-monitor-260nw-1033361050.jpg
"https:\\u002F\\u002Fimage.shutterstock.com\\u002Fimage-vector\\u002Fman-standing-looks-lcd-monitor-260nw-1033361050.jpg
```

Comment: Any secure URL that doesn't end in `jpg` will still start with `https`, so you get that URL and everything after it, until the regex runs into the first `jpg`. You either need to code for matching a URL accurately (a LOT of work), or you should consider parsing the html using a library like `bs4` or `lxml` and work from there.

Comment: Alternatively, if your URLs are enclosed in quotes, you may be able to match by starting with the quotes before `https` and only match anything *but* the quotes inside the URL with `[^"]+?` instead of `.+?`

Comment: Why not use a proper HTML parser? If I recall correctly, lxml.html even provides a method to iterate over all the links on the page.

Comment: That was Grismar, thank you very much!